# Accessing files in rails assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, svg, erb

I want to access files in assets directory of a rails project, from a ERB file:

```
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="assets/svg/images.svg#icon_location"></use>
</svg>
```

But the files won't load, if i put the the folder in public and not in assets then it loading.

I have tried stuff like image_tag() but not succeeded (Ruby on rails newbie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="<%=image_path("svg/images.svg")%>#icon_location"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: can you insert a html part that is produced by the code I suggested? And what version of rails do you use?

Comment: Also, please ensure that your svg is located in `rails_root/app/assets/images/svg` folder. Otherwise, please write where is your folder with svg files is located